# Joint density function: $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{x^3}{2} e^{-x(y+1)}$. Find $\mathbb{E} (Y|X)$, $\mathbb{E} (Y^2|X^2)$ and $\mathbb{P} (Y>1|X^3 + 1)$.

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation, density-function

Given joint density function of $(X,Y)$:
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{x^3}{2} e^{-x(y+1)} \ \text{ for: } \ x,y > 0$$

Find $\mathbb{E} (Y|X)$, $\mathbb{E} (Y^2|X^2)$ and $\mathbb{P} (Y>1|X^3 + 1)$.

---

For $\mathbb{E} (Y|X)$:

$$f_X(x) = \int_y f_{X,Y}(x,y) \ dy = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^3}{2} e^{-x(y+1)} \ dy = \frac{x^2 e^{-x}}{2} \  \text{ when: } \ x>0 \ \text{ and } 0 \text{ otherwise. }$$

So we have that:

$$\mathbb{E}(Y|X) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{y \cdot f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)} \ dy = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{y \cdot \frac{x^3}{2} e^{-x(y+1)}}{\frac{x^2 e^{-x}}{2}} \ dy = \int_0^{\infty} yxe^{-xy} \ dy = \frac{1}{x}$$

---

For $\mathbb{E} (Y^2|X^2)$:

As @GérardLetac said, since we know that $X > 0$, when we have $X^2$ that implies that we have $X$.

Therefore we have that

$$h(X) = \mathbb{E}(Y^2|X) \implies g(X^2) = h( \sqrt{X^2}) = \mathbb{E}(Y^2|X^2)$$

So we need to calculate only $\mathbb{E}(Y^2|X)$:

$$\mathbb{E}(Y^2|X) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{y^2 \cdot f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)} \ dy = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{y^2 \cdot \frac{x^3}{2} e^{-x(y+1)}}{\frac{x^2 e^{-x}}{2}} \ dy = \int_0^{\infty} y^2xe^{-xy} \ dy = \frac{2}{x^2}$$

And we have that: $\mathbb{E}(Y^2|X^2) = \frac{2}{x^2}$

---

For $\mathbb{P} (Y>1|X^3 + 1)$:

As @GérardLetac said:

$$ h(X) = \mathbb{P}(Y > 1| X) \implies \mathbb{P}(Y > 1| X^3 + 1) = g(X) = h((X-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}) $$

Therefore we need to calculate only $\mathbb{P}(Y > 1| X)$ and put $(x-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ in place of $x$:
$$\mathbb{P}(Y > 1| X) = \int_1^{\infty} \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)} dy = \int_1^{\infty} \frac{\frac{x^3}{2} e^{-x(y+1)}}{\frac{x^2 e^{-x}}{2}} dy =  \int_1^{\infty} xe^{-xy} dy = e^{-x}$$

So we have that $\mathbb{P}(Y > 1| X^3 + 1) = e^{-\sqrt[3]{x-1}}$

Comment: You have to find the joint density of $(X^2,Y^2)$.

Comment: Since $X>0$, the knowledge of $X^2$ gives the knowledge of $X.$  Therefore $h(X)=E(g(Y)|X)$ implies that $h_1(X^2)=h(\sqrt{X^2})=E(g(Y)|X^2)!$

Comment: @GérardLetac I don't know if I understand how to do it. Are you talking about $E(Y^2|X^2)$? What is the function of $g$?

Comment: @Surb I don't know how to do it tho. Is my $E(Y,X)$ correct at least?

Comment: I'm writing an answer to this question.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Ok, thank you! Meanwhile, I will edit my question because at this point I think I know hot to do $E(Y|X)$ and $E(Y^2|X^2)$.

Comment: @mathman12 For what it's worth, the computation of $\mathbb E[Y|X]$ is correct, and I will also be adding the entire derivation of $\mathbb E[Y^2|X^2]$.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer ok, great. Thank you for help!

Comment: Welcome as always!

Comment: Well,  1) Your $f_x(y)$ is quite correct. 2) You ask: is my $ E(Y|X)$ correct at last? but I have not seen your calculation of $\int_0^{\infty}yf_x(y)dy$ 3) You ask 'what is $g$? Answer: any function that you need in particular $g(y)=y^2$. I explained this more general case in order to distract you from the foolish suggestion to compute the joint distribution of ($X^2,Y^2).$  4) Finally $\Pr(Y>1|X)= h(X)$ implies $\Pr(Y>1|X^3+1)=h_1(X)=h((X-1)^{1/3}).$

Comment: @GérardLetac I think I get it now. I will be back with a new update! Thank you!

Comment: Oh hang on, just a minute. According to the formula here, $f_{Y|X}(y|x) =\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}$. You seem to have divided by $f_Y(y)$ instead of $f_X(x)$. Even I made this mistake without noticing it!

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer yeah, you are right, my bad. I'm on it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to sleep so I can't finish this (went down the wrong alley for a long time!). If this is unanswered tomorrow I'll make sure to add an answer. Do add one if you are able to finish the problem. Thanks and +1.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I think I have $E(Y|X)$ at last. Through the night I will try to do $E(Y^2|X^2)$ and $P(Y>1|X^3 + 1)$. I think I have a decent chance of solving $E(Y^2|X^2)$. I am not sure about the other one. Thank you very much for your help! Have a good night :)

Comment: @GérardLetac Ok, I think I get it a bit. But by that logic, if $E(X|Y) = \frac{1}{x}$, then $E(Y^2|X^2) = \frac{1}{x^2}$? Or do I need to find some function $h$ and put $x^2$ in it to get $E(Y^2|X^2)$?

Comment: I expected to calculate something like $E(Y^2|X^2) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{y^2 \cdot f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)} \ dy$

Comment: Ohhh I think I get it now. We have that $E(Y^2|X) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{y^2 \cdot f_{X,Y} (x,y)}{f_X(x)}$ and having that function, when we put $x^2$ in place of $x$ we obtain $E(Y^2|X^2)$. Is that correct @GérardLetac ? I will edit my original post with that in mind.

Comment: I am embarrassed because the discussion relies on question of convention of notation about conditional expectations. When we consider $E(g(Y)|X)$ the result should be expressed as a function of $X$, say $h(X)$. Similarly if $Z=k(X)$ where $k$ is some one to one function, then when we consider $E(g(Y)|Z)$ the result should be expressed as a function of $Z$, say $h_1(Z)$. But  frankly, if $k^{-1}$ denotes the inverse function of $k$ certainly the notation $$E(g(Y)|Z)=h_1(k^{-1})(X)=h(X)$$ is clearer and more natural. This is a nasty exercise.

Comment: Now I think it is finally correct. Thank you for help @GérardLetac - you have great patience. Sorry for all the questions which were kind of stupid as I look at it right now.

Comment: I won't need to write an answer, the one below is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate $X\sim\text{Gamma}(k=3, \theta=1)$, and $Y\vert X=x\sim \text{Exponential}(\lambda=x).$

You can check that this gives the right joint density:
$$f(x,y)=f_x(x)f_{y|x}(y\vert x) \propto (x^{3-1}e^{-x})(xe^{-yx}) = x^3e^{-x(y+1)}.$$
Using well-known [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Properties) of the Exponential distribution, we have
$$\mathbb{E}\left[Y\vert X=x\right]= \frac{1}{x}.$$

Using your/@GérardLetac's observation that $x\mapsto x^2$ and $x\mapsto x^3+1$ are 1-1 functions for $x>0$,  we similarly compute

$$ \mathbb{E}\left[Y^2\vert X=x\right]= \frac{2!}{x^2}=\frac{2}{x^2},$$

and

$$P(Y>1\vert X=x)= e^{-x},$$

hence
$$P(Y>1\vert X^3+1=u)=e^{-\sqrt[3]{u-1}}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your input! I edited my original question according to hints given by 2 users in the comments (I can't mention them both here in one comment). I got the same solutions as you did, so I guess they are correct. Could you please tell me if there are any errors in my way of thinking (presented now in my question)? I will accept your answer as the one that solved the problem.